# a-an consonant starting words

Tags: articles, consonants

Is there some special rule regarding articles  for words starting with two consonants? I was taught to use **a** when a word starts with consonant (or an otherwise). I just wrote "a mPOS device" but MS Word proposes to use "an". I can hear "emPOs". Is this a special rule or the Word spell checker bug? Thanks

Comment: It is what you can hear that the rule regarding *a* and *an* applies to, so I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: It is not the letter that the next word starts with that counts  but the sound. See [this comment](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33505/does-one-use-a-or-an-in-this-case#comment62793_33505). Since mPOS starts with a vowel sound, use *an*. (That is the traditional rule, although it doesn't describe how all native speakers actually speak.)

Comment: I see. So the pronounciation is the rule.

Comment: Yes, sir, it is the pronunciation that is the rule.

Comment: Think of it this way: adding in the "-n" separates two spoken vowels which would be akward to say one after the other. Try saying "a apple" and "an apple" or "an mPOS" and "a mPOS". The way you say it reflects back on how you write it - a or an.

Comment: This is diccussed at length here: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6760/should-individual-letters-be-preceded-with-an/6762#6762

Comment: You would wonder how akward my native language is :-) For example this is absolutely correct sentence composed of just consonants: "Strč prst skrz krk" (put finger through throat). We have many words having 3-4 consonants in a row.